# How to handle field with multiple items

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have created a field with unlimited number of values allowed. Now, using view I want to display all even number items (like 2nd, 4th, 6th and so on). How can I do that?

My thought: May be I need to edit **views-view-field.html.twig** file. But I'm not finding any way to display items in field instead of complete field. Please help me.

View source of views-view-field.html.twig:

{{ output -}}

Comment: You can override the individual field template  and only print the even items in twig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard field handler in Views returns flat rendered output. To change this or put in the feature for even/odd numbered values you would need to implement a field handler plugin. For this task that would be a bit too much work. You can improvise in theming to get the same result.

In Views you can define a separator for multiple field values. Choose a separator that is not in the content of the field. Default is `','`.

In Twig you can use the filter `split` to get the array `items`. Use the separator from the multiple field settings.

**views-view-field--field-fieldname.html.twig**

```
{% set items = output|split(',') %}
```

Put `items` in a loop and display only even number items:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if loop.index is even %}
    {{ item }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried this solution for a similar issue. I think it's worth noting that the |split() filter will provide you with markup, so you will likely need to apply a |raw filter on the item; eg. {{ item|raw }}